# How to use loc on a time series dataframe with strftime formatting date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-series

I used this code:
`df_3 = df_2.groupby(df_2.index.strftime('%A %H:%M')).mean()`
to create a dataframe that contains the mean of each timestamp for each weekday which looks like this:

| date_col | Available |
| --- | --- |
| Friday 00:00 | 512.805556 |
| Friday 00:05 | 515.184211 |
| Friday 00:10 | 514.631579 |
| Friday 00:15 | 517.477273 |

But I'm not sure how to locate one record based on the index. When I try with the displayed timestamp as a string, like `df_3.iloc[['Friday 00:05']]` it throws an error but how would I refer to that value? date_col is the index

Answer (score 1):

If your date is your index use `loc`, `iloc` is used to access by row number:

```
df_3.loc[['Friday 00:05']]
```

else, first set `date_col` as index:

```
df_3.set_index('date_col')
```

also, you can access the row without setting the `date_col` as index:

```
df_3[df_3['date_col']=='Friday 00:05']
```

Comment: `groupby` sets the key as index by default, so if OP's command is correct date_col should be the index. ;)

Comment: @mozway, i know, but the provided sample shows something else.